# Full stack testing Ember.js and Laravel app

Tags: node.js, laravel, ember.js, bdd, cucumberjs

I am working out how best to test an application we are developing using Laravel as backend (REST API) and Ember.js as front end.

I am currently using Behat to run acceptance tests for the API. I would like to use Cucumber.js to also create and test features for the Ember side of the project.

I already have an "acceptance" environment dedicated to running the Behat features in the API.

The issue I can see with "full stack" testing from the JS side is how to clean and reseed the database?

My thoughts are to add a route for testing purposes only, e.g.:

```
if ( App::environment() == 'acceptance' ) {
    Route::get('/test/reseed', function() {
        // delete db if exists
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        // call other migrations...  
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
        return "ok";
    });
}
```

This way only the acceptance environment has access to that call, and it should be all thats needed to set up the API side of things ready for Cucumber.js & Ember to run the tests (probably via Node.js)

I'm asking here to see if there is anything glaring I might have missed, if there is another way to do this.

The reason I want to be able to test purely from the JS side is so that we can test the systems independently of each other. I am aware I can test the full application with Behat, Mink and PhantomJS for example.